# Data not displayed present in current table but not present in another table

Tags: mysql

I want to display data in code column in `templates_boxes` table whose id is not present in another table `templates_boxes_to_pages` and here is my code for that.
I want to display the data in code column but it is not displayed.

```
select tb.code from table_template_to_boxes tb
  left join mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages tbtp on tb.id = tbtp.templates_boxes_id
  where tbtp.templates_id = 3
    and tb.modules_group = 'boxes'
    and tbtp.templates_boxes_id is null
```

Comment: What is the error msg??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Not sure what is your error.

```
select tb.code from templates_boxes tb where tb.id not in (select templates_boxes_id from templates_boxes_to_pages where templates_id = 3) and tb.modules_group = 'boxes'
```

Comment: getting this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'templates_boxes_to_pages where templates_id = 3) and tb.modules_group = 'boxes'' at line 1

Comment: Can you please check if the tables and the columns name I have used are correct?

Comment: @Tuhin What is your table name `templates_boxes_to_pages` or `mxp_templates_boxes_to_pages`

Comment: Hey thanks it worked :). . .actually there was a typo mistake by me. . .silly me ;).